# Attempt to accessing Vuex state after its cleanup

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a problem with cleaning up Vuex state at logout and continuing attempts to access to the state from the component.

1. A component uses object from state:

```
    <custom-card
        color="green"
        :name="this.author.name"
        :surname="this.author.surname"
    >
```

2. An "author" object is obtained using getters, from "computed":

```
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters({
            author: 'author'
        }),
    },
```

3. When I'm trying to logout being on the page with the card component, I am redirected to the login page (as intended) and at the same time I got an error in console:

```
    vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null"
    vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888 TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null
```

It's clear for me, that 'author' is set to null at logout and this is why the error occur. But it isn't clear for, why this is happening. I thought after click on logout button, vue-router should redirect me to the login page and content of the previous page doesn't matter after that.

How can I avoid these errors?

**Upd.** I think an anwer on this question can be found in "[Rectivity in Depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)" article on Vuejs documentation:

Since Vue doesn’t allow dynamically adding root-level reactive properties, you have to initialize Vue instances by declaring all root-level reactive data properties upfront, even with an empty value.
If you don’t declare message in the data option, Vue will warn you that the render function is trying to access a property that doesn’t exist.

Comment: You should add a safe-guard like this - `:name="(this.author || {}).name" :surname="(this.author || {}).surname"`

Comment: thanks, I modified getting values in computed section to avoid errors.